# Super Contest Winners: Week 3

Tags: discussion, super-contest

This post is to document the **week 3** winners of the [Super User Super Contest](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/super-user-1-year-anniversary-super-contest/), for the week ending **Monday, September 13**.

Congratulations to our winners this week!

1. [Best rookie](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/3/week/superuser/2010-09-06) performance by [**Brad**](https://superuser.com/users/48624/brad)

   [image: best rookie performance week of 08-30-2010]
2. [Highest reputation](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/3/week/superuser/2010-09-06) produced by [**Subanki**](https://superuser.com/users/46669/subanki)

   [image: top users week of 08-30-2010]
3. Best meta post:

   [Is it OK to downvote link only or link/copy/paste answers?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1393/is-it-ok-to-downvote-link-only-or-link-copy-paste-answers) by [**JNK**](https://meta.superuser.com/users/43645/jnk)
4. Most awesome new question or answer:

   [What is the origin of the hard drive light?](https://superuser.com/questions/185980/what-is-the-origin-of-the-hard-drive-light) by [**RCIX**](https://superuser.com/users/2130/rcix)

We are contacting the winners now, so be sure to check your email inboxes!

Comment: Oh MY GOD , I won a LCD 22" Monitor !! Hey is it a LCD TV or LCD Computer Monitor. I don't know much about these any suggestion on which Monitor is better.

Comment: Congrats to All Winners

Comment: OK as per the instructions I have sent the message but how will I know you people received my mail

Comment: Um. Its friggin' email. If it doesn't get delivered it will bounce back to you. If you're so paranoid setup a read response. @Subanki.

Comment: How in the world can the "hard drive light" question win?

Comment: @lance: why wouldn't it? :P

Comment: Why isn't any answer accepted

Answer (score 7):

Congrats to the winners :D

[image: close]

Comment: LOL Sathya, I thought it was closed :P (Creative Idea)

Comment: Hehe, nice. Glad to see you closed week two as well. But, you didn't even tweak it to say "answer"....

Comment: @DMA5 and hence it was closed as exact dupe ;)